# Can I store HTML as XML in a Sqlite3 database?

Tags: html, xml, database, sqlite

Is it possible to do this? The HTML files in question all conform to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

EDIT: How would you store a number of HTML pages with sequential IDs associated with them in a database? (Oh, I'm new to databases).

EDIT: Now I realise there is no "xml" datatype for SQlite. I had a wrong datasource open!

Comment: Your another question missed the point of all replies that you've got to your first one. SQLite _does not have_ an "XML data field". It has text fields, and it's up to you to interpret text inside the way you want. If you treat it as XML, then that's fine. And of course you can do anything that you can do with XML "with SQLite".

Comment: This is what happens when you move from Microsoft SQL Server to Sqlite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [TEXT datatype](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Sqlite doesn't care if your data is HTML or XML.

To store several HTML pages with a sequential number use a table like:

```
 CREATE TABLE pages
        (ID integer  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        html TEXT
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. If you store it in the database as a string, the database shouldn't care whether that string is plain text, XML, or SNOBOL.

Comment: If I were a database, I'd draw the line at SNOBOL.  Just saying.

Comment: + for making me laugh hehehe :P

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, XHTML is a specialized subset of XML. However, if the XHTML is not compliant (it may work in a browser, but it may not really be XML), you may run into problems.